# Is there event that triggers after DOM was loaded but before any external assets like images, styles,iframes, etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'd would also like to pause fetching of external files until my event function finishes, is it possible ? If not on clean JS, maybe with jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

[$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: You cant ensure that any file was loaded by calling DOM ready, think about a large DOM tree and a tiny css file loaded in the header. The question itself is wrong btw.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event cause you can't be ensure that no file was loaded before the DOM tree is build. Its an asynchrones process, where the DOM is parsed and builded. Whenever the parser comes to a link for an external file, he starts to load this. So when it could happend that some of these files are loaded before the parsed comes to the end of the body tag. Maybe you're looking for something different.